# Is this correct to do this inequality?

Tags: real-analysis

If I have :
$$\frac{u_k}{2} \ge \frac{u_{k+1}}{2}$$
Is this true to say that:
$$\frac{u_k}{2} + \frac{1}{u_k} \ge \frac{u_{k+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{u_{k+1}}$$

If yes, is there any "intuitive" explanation of why ? (I really can't figure it out)

If no, would you have any counter example?

Thank you !

Comment: You can safely say  that:  
$$\frac{u_k}{2} + \frac{1}{u_{k+1}} \ge \frac{u_{k+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{u_{k}}$$

Comment: @N74 Seems to be true only for positive $\{u_k\}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true in general, but it's true provided $u_{k+1} \ge \sqrt 2$. The function $f(x) = \frac x2 + \frac1x$ is increasing, and therefore order-preserving, for $x \ge \sqrt 2$, so
$$\frac{u_k}{2} \ge \frac{u_{k+1}}{2} \implies u_k \ge u_{k+1} \implies f(u_k) \ge f(u_{k+1}) \implies \frac{u_k}{2} + \frac1{u_k} \ge \frac{u_{k+1}}{2} + \frac1{u_{k+1}}.$$
To figure out that $f(x)$ is increasing for $x \ge \sqrt 2$, take the derivative. We get $f'(x) = \frac12 - \frac1{x^2}$, and $\frac12 - \frac1{x^2} \ge 0$ when $x^2 \ge 2$, or $x \ge \sqrt 2$.

(We also have $f'(x) \ge 0$ when $x \le -\sqrt 2$, because that gives us $x^2 \ge 2$ just the same. So I guess this statement is also true when $u_k$ and $u_{k+1}$ are both $\le -\sqrt2$.)

Comment: Wow actually I had just proven that the series elements are always $\ge$ than $\sqrt{2}$ ! Didn't thought there was a link between the two questions of the exercice.

Comment: But I don't really understand how you was able to see that it is true for $\sqrt{2}$

Comment: By taking the derivative; I've edited my answer to elaborate.

Answer (score 4):

This is not true in general. For example, for $u_k = 1$ and $u_{k+1} = 0.1$:

$$\frac{u_k}{2} \geqslant \frac{u_{k+1}}{2}$$
but
$$\frac{u_k}{2} + \frac{1}{u_k} \leqslant \frac{u_{k+1}}{2}+\frac{1}{u_{k+1}}$$